# Get all h2 text from main container, display them in sidebar

Tags: jquery, css

I would swear my code is right, but it seems not to be working. Here is my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/py5cvpmz/1/

And here is the jQuery code:

```
var searchArea = $('main');
var blockArea = $('.sidebar .container');
var blockDynamic = $('.block-dynamic ul');
var items = [];
var title;

blockArea.append('<div class="sidebar-item block-dynamic"><p>Sidebar menu</p><ul></ul></div>');

searchArea.find('h2').each(function(e) {
  title = $(this).text();
  items.push(title);
});

    $.each(items, function(i, val) {
      // When I use a console.log here to output 'val', it works fine
      blockDynamic.append('<li class="item-' + i + '">' + val + '</li>');
    });
```

Comment: sorry, I'm out of guesses today. what's the problem...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are caching `blockDynamic` before the element it is referencing is appended to `blockArea`. To see that your code works, move the declaration of `blockDynamic` after the append call.

```js
var searchArea = $('main');
var blockArea = $('.sidebar .container');
blockArea.append('<div class="sidebar-item block-dynamic"><p>Sidebar menu</p><ul></ul></div>');

var blockDynamic = $('.block-dynamic ul');

searchArea.find('h2').each(function(i, e) {
  var title = $(this).text();
  blockDynamic.append('<li class="item-' + i + '">' + title + '</li>');
});
```

```css
main {
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

main h2 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.sidebar {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background-color: #333;
}

.sidebar .container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">


</script>
<main>
  <h2>
this is a test h2
</h2>
  <h2>
this is another test h2
</h2>
  <h2>
this is, once again, a test h2
</h2>
  <h2>
this is the last test h2
</h2>
</main>
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Here I want all the H2 titles as menu items -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: damn. you beat me by a few sec. my bad...i've put a snippet too :)

Comment: @MaartenWolfsen as an exercise, you can clean up your code and remove one of those loops altogether.

Comment: @chazsolo Yeah, that is a good plan! This was just a prototype, but I will surely clean up my code! And to everyone else, I will give you all an upvote, for the help! :)

Comment: @MihaiT I know I always forget about the code snippets :)

Comment: @chazsolo like you said, I have cleaned the jQuery a bit: https://jsfiddle.net/wwpf8x1m/

Answer (score 2):

Element matching `.block-dynamic ul` doesn't exist by the time you try to get it.

You need to have something like this

```
blockArea.append('<div class="sidebar-item block-dynamic"><p>Sidebar menu</p><ul></ul></div>');
var blockDynamic = blockArea('.block-dynamic ul');
```

Notice that I moved `blockDynamic` initialization AFTER `blockArea` is appended with content.

Answer (score 1):

declare `var blockDynamic = $('.block-dynamic ul');` after you append the `ul` . because if you do it before, the `ul` does not exist so that variable is null

```js
var searchArea = $('main');
var blockArea = $('.sidebar .container');

var items = [];
var title;

blockArea.append('<div class="sidebar-item block-dynamic"><p>Sidebar menu</p><ul></ul></div>');
var blockDynamic = $('.block-dynamic ul');
searchArea.find('h2').each(function(e) {
  title = $(this).text();
  items.push(title);

});

$.each(items, function(i, val) {
  blockDynamic.append('<li class="item-' + i + '">' + val + '</li>');
});
```

```css
main {
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

main h2 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.sidebar {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background-color: #333;
}

.sidebar .container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">


</script>
<main>
  <h2>
this is a test h2
</h2>
  <h2>
this is another test h2
</h2>
  <h2>
this is, once again, a test h2
</h2>
  <h2>
this is the last test h2
</h2>
</main>
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Here I want all the H2 titles as menu items -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line var blockDynamic = $('.block-dynamic ul'); the element does not exist, if you want there, try this:

```
var blockDynamic = '.block-dynamic ul';
searchArea.find('h2').each(function(i) {
  $(blockDynamic).append('<li class="item-'+i+'">'+$(this).text()+'</li>');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

To get the h2 and not only its content:

```
searchArea.find('h2').each(function() {
  blockArea.append($(this).clone());
});
```